# How to find a nested selenium WebElement in C# with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, selenium

I've been learning about LINQ and am trying to apply it to finding certain web elements on the page with selenium.

I have an angular site which displays a table made up of divs. All the rows in a column, including the header, have the same attributes (e.g. css selector/classname etc).

I want to find all the input boxes within a column that are visible, and came up with this...

```
var applyBoxes2 = from box in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-apply.col-md-1"))
                  where box.Text != "Apply?"
                  select box;

var clickableBox = from box in applyBoxes2
                   where box.FindElement(By.TagName("input")).Displayed == true
                   select box.FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
```

The first query is required as the first row is the header, and doesn't contain an input field. If I don't have this query my second query will fall over when trying to do the findelement = "input".

Does anybody know if I can combine these 2 statements? So first I would filter out the header, then I would find each input box within each div.

Any thoughts on how else this could be improved on would be welcomed.

Many thanks,

Comment: Can't you extend the first one, eg. `where box.Text != "Apply?"` > `&&` <? && Short circuits if the 1st fails so it won't try to find it when the text is Apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `&&` operator, it short circuits when it doesn't pass the 1st statement. So in your case it won't try to find an element if the text is `Apply?`.

```
var clickableBox = from box in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-apply.col-md-1"))
                              where box.Text != "Apply?" && box.FindElement(By.TagName("input")).Displayed == true
                              select box.FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause,
to perform inner clause.

Code will be like this:

```
var applyBoxes2 = from box in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-apply.col-md-1"))
let clickableBox = box.FindElement(By.TagName("input"))
                  where box.Text != "Apply?" && clickableBox?.Displayed = True 
                  select clickableBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var clickableBox = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.col-apply.col-md-1"))
    .Where(box => box.Text != "Apply?")
    .Select(box => box.FindElement(By.TagName("input")))
    .Where(boxElement => boxElement.Displayed);
```